# .NET Code setup in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am new to .NET development and I am setting up a project in Visual studio 2010 with DevExpress 12.2.6 version.

When I build the project, I get this error:

> Error  25  'DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.FieldOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseCurrentCultureDateTimeFormat' and no extension method 'UseCurrentCultureDateTimeFormat' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.FieldOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Development\Support\SecurityMasterMonitor\SuppWikiSearchProcessInfoForm.Designer.cs    145 50  SecurityMasterMonitor

I have added `DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.dll` in my project refernece as well. I am not sure what is missing here.. Can you please help me?

Comment: What about code producing this error while being built? Can you show it or we should deduce somehow?

Comment: Check compatibility of .NET framework version of your project and that of the dll

Comment: Either the wrong version of DevExpress or the wrong .NET framework. Probably wrong versin of DevExpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DevExpress support forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B201979) concerning version 2012 vol 2.7 (i.e. 12.2.7)

> The DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.FieldOptions.UseCurrentCultureDateTimeFormat property is implemented. It is accessible using RichEditControl.Options.Fields.UseCurrentCultureDateTimeFormat notation.

So, as you can see - you need either upgrade to 12.2.7 or don't use `UseCurrentCultureDateTimeFormat` in your code since it was implemented in version 12.2.7.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. Let me check version and compatibilty.

Comment: I updated DevExpress to 12.2.7 version and now everything is working. Thank you so much